# Адаптивное меню не срабатывает при нажатии на триггер

Tags: html, jquery, css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть адаптивное меню которое должно сворачиваться при нажатии на триггер(гамбургер)
HTML:

`<span class="main-nav-trigger">&#9776;</span> ///сам триггер который должен сворачиваться 
      <ul class="horizontal-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>`

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function menu() {
  var $trigger = $('.main-nav-trigger'),
      $menu = $('.horizontal-nav');

  $trigger.click(function() {
    $(this).next($menu).slideToggle();
  });
  }});
```

CSS:

```
   //trigger
.main-nav-trigger {
  display: none ;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:#fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}
//media 992 px
@media (max-width: 992px){
  .main-nav-trigger {
    display: block ;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.main-nav-trigger').click(function() {
     $(this).next('.horizontal-nav').slideToggle();
   });
```

});